# Reactor use doOnNext multiple times

Tags: reactor

I was trying to change a little reactor samples from [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/projectreactor/samples/FluxSamples.java) and I'm a little confused with the behaviour I get.

So first I code like this:

```
    EmitterProcessor<String> stream = EmitterProcessor.<String>create().connect();
    Flux<String> flux = stream
            .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("1 " + s))
            .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("2 " + s));
    flux.subscribe();
    stream.onNext("Hello");
```

This code prints two lines as expected:

```
1 Hello
2 Hello
```

But if I add an intermediate varaible pretending I get it from some method or for readability the code starts to behave differently.

```
    EmitterProcessor<String> stream = EmitterProcessor.<String>create().connect();
    Flux<String> flux = stream
            .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("1 " + s));
    flux .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("2 " + s));
    flux.subscribe();
    stream.onNext("Hello");
```

So for the code above I get only one line, that is:

```
1 Hello
```

Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Stephane Maldini I realised that Flux is immutable and each operation produces different flows.
Discussion is [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/278)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some code snippet will help people understand quickly, in your second code example:

`flux.doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("2 " + s));`

should be changed to:

`flux = flux.doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("2 " + s));`